# Saltstack Accessing pillar inside salt['cmd.run']

Tags: saltstack

I'm trying to configure a state that will look at the home directories of the system, and iterate through them to check for specific files. To accomplish this I originally wrote up:

```
{% for userdir in salt['cmd.run']('ls /home').split('\n') %}
```

for my loop, and that works great. However, I want to make it easily configerable for alternate environments, so I had thought to store home directory locations inside a pillar, and changed the line to:

```
{% for userdir in salt['cmd.run']('ls pillar['home']').split('\n') %}
```

which gave a `Jinja syntax error: expected token 'comma', got 'home';` i assume because of the double sets of embeded `'`'s

so I tried:

```
{% for userdir in salt['cmd.run']('ls pillar["home"]').split('\n') %}
```

which gave me: `Rendering SLS failed: mapping values are not allowed here;`

I've looked at a as many pillar loop situations as I can to try and find an example I can work off of, but it doesn't seem to exist.

is it possible to call pillar information from within the ls? Or is there a better way to accomplish this goal?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to do your mapping outside the string:

`{% for userdir in salt['cmd.run']('ls '+pillar['home']).split('\n') %}`